# Methods LocationManager:didEnterRegion and LocationManager:didExitRegion is getting called continuously

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon, estimote, beacon

I am developing a Beacon iOS application. However I am facing an issue. I have found out that when the *beacon device* is at a certain distance away from the iPhone, both the methods **LocationManager:didEnterRegion** and **LocationManager:didExitRegion** keeps getting called repeatedly in a random manner. What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. If you're on the edge of reception it actually makes sense that those delegate methods would be called and it might actually appear random. If you go further away from the beacon the last delegate method called should be the didExitRegion: though and vice versa.

Comment: While it is normal for this to happen on the edge of the beacon's transmission range, beacons with a weak transmitter will behave this way over a wider band of distances.  Increasing the transmitter power (configurable on many beacon models) will push the distance where this starts to happen further away, potentially making it less of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you removing and re-adding the region you are monitoring inside one or both of the did enter/exit region callbacks? If so, remove them